# iTunes unsubmitted app version number change

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have one app already publish and under sales status , its version is 1.0. Now we want a major update of this app with version 2.0 . But I have by mistake create app version 1.1 , Now don't able to understand how I can change it 1.1 to 2.0 .  Currently 1.1 version app is "Prepare for Submission" status

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In iTunes Connect you should be able to change the store version number (this is under your app icon and app ID). This value can be different to what your build and version number are in Xcode, this is what your users will see. You should be able to edit this in the Prepare for Submission status as well as the In Review Status I believe.

If you want to update the version number in Xcode as well, just change the version number under 'general' in your target and submit a new build.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help , don;t know I miss this